# Estimate the average number of prime factors of a 1000-digit number

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics

More formally, find an asymptotic for $N\to\infty$ of
$$\frac{\sum_{1\le k\le N} M(k)}{N}$$ where
$$M(p_1^{d_1}p_2^{d_2}\cdots p_k^{d_k}) = d_1+d_2+\cdots+d_k$$

For example, $M(24) = M(2^3\cdot3) = 4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out equation (3) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFactor.html). Unsurprisingly, the first term in the series is the same as the one for the distinct divisor function $\omega(n)$, namely $\log \log n$.

Comment: Well, I supposed that the answer should be $\log \log N + constant$, thanks for a reference

Answer (score 0):

equation (20) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFactor.html gives the exact answer as $\log \log N +B$ for some constant B. The link gives reference to what the value of B is.