# The average number of prime factors of a number less than or equal to $N$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm just curious, are there statistical results about counting prime factors, in a sense of the fundamental theorem of arithmetics, of a very large numbers? For example, the average prime factor count of a number less than or equal to 10 is $\overline{P}(10)=(0+1+1+2+1+2+1+3+2+2)/10 = 3/2.$

Formally let

$$
\overline{P}(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \Omega (n)
$$

where $\Omega(n)$ is the function that counts prime factors with multiplicity.

Comment: See [the Prime Number Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Comment: See: [Estimate the average number of prime factors of a 1000-digit number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51083/estimate-the-average-number-of-prime-factors-of-a-1000-digit-number)

Comment: See also [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function#Average_order_and_summatory_functions), which gives $\bar{P}(n)\sim \log\log n + 1.0345$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog  should be $ \log \log n + 0.26149721284764 $

Comment: Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem) theorem,